# Refused to apply style and 404 Error using Express and React build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am trying to serve my React app via an Express server with the following code:

```
// server/app.ts
app.use(express.static(path.join('/home/bram/Documents/Tool/build/', "static")));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join('/home/bram/Documents/Tool/build/', 'index.html'));
});
```

I am using absolute paths at the moment just to make sure that I am indeed pointing to the correct directory. But unfortunately, when I try to load the app in my browser, I get the following output:
[image]
The `index.html` file created by the React build process contains the following code:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:400,400i|IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed:400,400i|IBM+Plex+Sans:100,100i,400,400i,700,700i|IBM+Plex+Serif:400,400i" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>React App</title>
      <link href="/static/css/main.09c2cd91.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.3bf29127.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I believe that the paths to the stylesheet and js files look fine in here.
I have the following folder structure:

- build

  - static

    - css

      - main.09c2cd91.css
      - main.09c2cd91.css.map
    - js

      - main.3bf29127.js
      - main.3bf29127.js.map
    - media

      - coins.c39b5ed2.ttf
  - asset-manifest.json
  - manifest.json
  - favicon.ico
  - index.html
  - service-worker.js
- server

  - app.ts
  - ...
- ...

I first thought that maybe I screwed something up when I ejected my React app, but I can still start the app (without completely building it) so I am guessing that is not it. Any one an idea?

## EDIT

Using the static middleware to point directly to the js, media and css folders has been proposed. I updated my code as follows:

```
app.use(express.static("/home/bram/Documents/Trading_Tool/TGP-Crypto-Trading-Tool/build/static"));
app.use(express.static("/home/bram/Documents/Trading_Tool/TGP-Crypto-Trading-Tool/build/static/css"));
app.use(express.static("/home/bram/Documents/Trading_Tool/TGP-Crypto-Trading-Tool/build/static/js"));
app.use(express.static("/home/bram/Documents/Trading_Tool/TGP-Crypto-Trading-Tool/build/static/media"));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join('/home/bram/Documents/Trading_Tool/TGP-Crypto-Trading-Tool/build/', 'index.html'));
});
```

This did unfortunately not fix the issue.

## EDIT 2

I am unsure whether this is going to be useful extra info but my `asset-manifest.json` file looks like the following:

```
{
  "main.css": "static/css/main.09c2cd91.css",
  "main.css.map": "static/css/main.09c2cd91.css.map",
  "main.js": "static/js/main.3bf29127.js",
  "main.js.map": "static/js/main.3bf29127.js.map",
  "static/media/coins.ttf": "static/media/coins.c39b5ed2.ttf"
}
```

Comment: Since you are including "static" in the path argument for the express static middleware, the paths in the HTML file are interpreted as relative to the static dir. That means you should remove "static" from the paths in your HTML

Comment: @PatrickHund I originally tried it without the static middleware but I got the same error. That is why I tried it with the static middleware.

Comment: You misunderstood. Using the static middleware is correct, but the paths in your html shouldn’thave the string „static“ in them, they have to point to „js“ and „css“ directly

Comment: @PatrickHund I tried that (see code under *EDIT* in my question) but without any luck.

Comment: Pointing to the files instead of the folders does also not work.